# Regular Expression for getting everything after last slash

Tags: regex

I was browsing stackoverflow and have noticed a regular expression for matching everything after last slash is

```
([^/]+$)
```

So for example if you have http://www.blah.com/blah/test
The reg expression will extract 'test' without single quotes.

My question is why does it do it? Doesn't ^/ mean beginning of a slash?

EDIT:
I guess I do not understand how +$ grabs "test". + repeats the previous item once or more so it ignores all data between all the / slashes. how does then $ extract the test

Comment: An awesome resource for these kinds of questions is http://regexr.com (go here: http://regexr.com?2vpj8 for your actual expression and if you hover over each part of it, you get a nice description of what that rule does).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, an `^` inside `[]` means negation.

`[/]` stands for 'any character in set [/]'.

`[^/]` stands for 'any character not in set [/]'.

Comment: I guess I do not understand how +$ grabs "test". + repeats the previous item once or more so it ignores all data between all the / slashes. how does then $ extract the test.

Comment: @CodeCrack `[^/]` matches one non-slash; `[^/]+` matches the first non-slashes only substring; `[^/]+$` matches the non-slashes substring right at the end of what you test.

Comment: Please edit the answer to speak directly to the question instead of just having it in the comments.

Answer (score 85):

In original question, just a `backslash` is needed `before slash`, in this case regex will get `everything after last slash` in the string

```
([^\/]+$)
```

Comment: escaping "/" is not needed when inside "[ ]"

Answer (score 8):

Just fyi, for a non-regex version of this, depending on the language you're in, you could use a combination of the substring and lastIndexOf methods. Just find the last index of the "/" character, and get the substring just after it.

i.e., in Java

```
String targetString = "a/string/with/slashes/in/it";
int lastSlashIndex = targetString.lastIndexOf('/');
String everythingAfterTheFinalSlash = targetString.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Within brackets, ^/ means NOT A /.  So this is matching a sequence of non-/'s up to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

`^` at the start of `[]` is character class negation. `[...]` specifies a set of characters to match. `[^...]` means match every character *except* that set of characters.

So `[^/]` means match every possible character except `/`.

Answer (score 0):

if you put the ^ in a group it says all charters not in this group.  So match all charter that are not slashes until the end of line $ anchor.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `^` means different things depending on context. When inside a character class (the `[]` ), the `^` negates the expression, meaning "match anything except `/`.

Outside of `[]`, the `^` means what you just said.

Comment: I have a simillar problem
I have `/db/env/dbo/analytical/data_from_google/sys_year=2022/sys_month=05/sys_day=14/part-00073-a4022c1a-c8a2-4af9-8289-0c3e514396e8.c002` how to use regexp to receive `/db/env/dbo/analytical/data_from_google/sys_year=2022/sys_month=05/sys_day=14/` i mean remove everything after last "/"