# Regex for matching everything after second-to-last backslash

Tags: c#, regex

Via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945477/regular-expression-for-getting-everything-after-last-slash) I found a way to get the last part of a string after a slash.

I need to use a slight modification of this:

I could use a regex that would match "Everything after the second-to-last backslash".

I rewrote the original to use backslash like this:

```
([^\\]+$)
```

And I made this code and test

```
public static string TrimTrail(this string value, string pattern)
{
    var regEx = new Regex(pattern);
    var result = regEx.Match(value);
    return result.Value;
}

[Test]
public void TestOfTrimmingTrail()
{
    //Arrange
    var stringToTest = @"0001 Lorem ipsum dolor sit\011 tortor neque\ 0111\interdum magn";
    var pattern = @"([^\\]+$)";
    //Act
    var result = stringToTest.TrimTrail(pattern);
    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(" 0111\\interdum magn", result);
}
```

But since I haven't been able to figure out the "second-to-last" requirement, it only returns

```
  Expected string length 19 but was 13. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: " 0111\\interdum magn"
  But was:  "interdum magn"
  -----------^
```

I tried adding a `{2}` before the negation char, but with no luck.
Can you help me figure out the remaining part?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
@"[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$"
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D%2B%5C%5C%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D%2B%24&i=0001%20Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%5C011%20tortor%20neque%5C%200111%5Cinterdum%20magn)

The `[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$` matches

- `[^\\]+` - 1 or more symbols other than `\`
- `\\` -  a literal `\`
- `[^\\]+` - 1 or more symbols other than `\`
- `$` - end of string.

In C#, a more efficient way to match some substring at the end is using `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` modifier. Use it to make this regex search more efficient.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/DJM5rp):

```
var line = @"0001 Lorem ipsum dolor sit\011 tortor neque\ 0111\interdum magn";
var pattern = @"[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$";
var result = Regex.Match(line, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
if (result.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(result.Value); // => " 0111\interdum magn"
```

Just a comparison of the regex effeciency with and without RTL option at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.com/tester):

[image]